# Parsing an array of chars for strings without for-loops?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, parsing, char

I have a program that takes in a user input which can range from a 5 char command like "help" and to also support flag-type commands like "delete -p 'George'"

I don't have much experience with c++, other than doing a bunch of for loops, was wondering if there was a more effective way to parse the array of char.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse command line options, check out [`boost::program_options`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp523371328)

Comment: You are asking for a "more effective way". More effective than what, what is your current solution?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from boost library as suggested in the comment, if you're parsing a relative small set of arguments, you can use simple `std::cin` for taking in arguments as the programme runs, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    std::string arg;
    while(std::cin >> arg) {
        args.push_back(arg);
    }
}
```

The above requires an EOF(not carriage return) to mark the end of commands.

For carriage return to mark the end of command, you'll need `getline()`, as demonstrated:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_args() {
    using std::string;
    using std::stringstream; // don't forget to include <sstream> header

    string line;
    getline(std::cin, line);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << line;

    std::vector<string> cmds;
    string cmd;
    while (ss >> cmd) {
        cmds.push_back(cmd);
    }

    return cmds;
}
```

Or if you'd like your main function to take arguments:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     // The call to the excutable itself will be the 0th element of this vector
     std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can assign an char array to string like this:

```
char array[5] = "test";
string str (array);
cout << str;
```

output :

```
test
```